# Add one column to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have multiple txt files and each of these txt files has 6 columns. What I want to do : add just one column as a last column, so at the end the txt file has maximum 7 columns and if **i run the script again it **shouldn't add** a new one**:

At the beginning each file has six columns:

```
     637.39 718.53 155.23 -0.51369 -0.18539 0.057838 3.209840789730089 
     636.56 720 155.57 -0.51566 -0.18487 0.056735 3.3520643559939938 
     635.72 721.52 155.95 -0.51933 -0.18496 0.056504 3.4997850701290125
```

What I want is to add a new column of zeros only if the current number of columns is 6, after that  it should prevent adding a new column when I run the script again (7 columns is the total number where the last one is zeros):

```
     637.39 718.53 155.23 -0.51369 -0.18539 0.057838 3.209840789730089 0
     636.56 720 155.57 -0.51566 -0.18487 0.056735 3.3520643559939938   0
     635.72 721.52 155.95 -0.51933 -0.18496 0.056504 3.4997850701290125 0
```

My code works and add one additional column each time i run the script but i want to add just once when the number of columns 6. Where (a) give me the number of column and if the condition is fulfilled then add a new one:

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
new_column = [0] * 20

def get_new_line(t):
    l, c = t
    return '{} {}\n'.format(l.rstrip(), c)

def writecolumn(filepath):
    # Load data from file
    with open(filepath) as datafile: 
         lines = datafile.readlines()
         a=np.loadtxt(lines, dtype='str').shape[1]
         print(a)
         **#if a==6:    (here is the problem)**
         n, r = divmod(len(lines), len(new_column))
         column = new_column * n + new_column[:r]
         new_lines = list(map(get_new_line, zip(lines, column)))
    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
         f.writelines(new_lines)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepaths = glob("/home/experiment/*.txt")
    for path in filepaths:
        writecolumn(path)
```

When i check the number of columns  **#if a==6 and shift the content inside the if statement** I get error. without shifting the content inside the if every thing works fine and still adding one column each time i run it.
Any help is appreciated.

To test the code create two/one txt files with random number of six columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be an indentation problem, i.e. block below 'if'.  writing new-lines should be indented properly --

This works  --

```
def writecolumn(filepath):
# Load data from file
    with open(filepath) as datafile: 
        lines = datafile.readlines()
        a=np.loadtxt(lines, dtype='str').shape[1]
        print(a)
        if int(a)==6:    
            n, r = divmod(len(lines), len(new_column))
            column = new_column * n + new_column[:r]
            new_lines = list(map(get_new_line, zip(lines, column)))
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                 f.writelines(new_lines)
```

Comment: I got the following error:    with open(filepath) as datafile:
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block . Another thing, with open(filepath) is outside the writecolumn function

Comment: just check in your editor it should be ( 4 spaces from 'if' line )

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I just modify a little bit your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to read your text file:

```
import pandas as of
df = pd.read_csv("whitespace.csv", header=None, delimiter=" ")
```

Add a column or more as needed

```
df['somecolname'] = 0
```

Save DataFrame with no header.

Comment: I am using txt files not csv. This is my data format and i don't want to change my code to deal with csv files. My question is a part of a big code. I am not dealing with one file as well, bet thanks

Comment: CSV is a text file with values separated by commas or in your case single spaces and no header line. So, the proposed solution does not change the format of your file.

Comment: In fact, you may just want to read the first line, use split to figure out the number of columns.

Comment: This line give me the number of columns: a=np.loadtxt(lines, dtype='str').shape[1], Each time i run the script, it adds new column of zeros which i don't want. (I have 6 columns and it should add only once whatever of times i run the  script and only when the number of columns are 6)

Comment: Well, pick up one line and split it to determine how many columns you have.